# How do i make a button click event happen when i click on another function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay the question sound strange at first but its not that bad. I want a vertical menu with multiple submenus. Ive tried with css and checkboxes first because i want to click on the menu to display submenu and not hover. Didn't work out the right solution. Now I found something on w3 but it still not work as i intented it to work. Submenu opens on click but if I click on another button with same script (but different class and id) they both stay opened. (If you open the bottom first the other makes it close but it happens only with the bottom one..)
https://jsfiddle.net/8vsbe5w3/

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown2">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------- */
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-content, .dropdown-content2{
  display: none;}
.show {display: block;}
```

My ideal menu would let you open only one submenu and allow to close it if you click on it again (uncheck the input).

Comment: Javascript is not Java, in the same way that Australia is not Austria. Please be careful when tagging your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `window.onclick` property twice, so you are overwriting the first one. That's why when you open the first menu and then the second, the first one stays open - because the first `window.onclick` doesn't exist anymore.

My advise is to refactor the code, so that you have only one `window.onclick` handler that works universally for both menus.

Also it's a bad idea to overwrite this even handler, better use `document.addEventListener()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ive never used event listener before, so im not sure if ive used it correctly (everything works as intented btw). So what i did is replace the `window.onclick = function(event)` with `window.addEventListener('click', function(event)` so the whole html looks like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dkj2grLy/)

Answer (score 0):

- Avoid **[on-event attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)**

  > `<button` <del>onclick="namedFunction()"</del> `></button>`
- use on-event property or `.addEventListener()`

  > `document.querySelector("button").onclick = namedFunction`
  >   `document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", namedFunction)`
- I there's multiple targets that are identical (HTML layout, CSS styles, JavaScript behavior, etc.),

  - use class avoid id.
  - find an ancestor element that all targets have in common. Although Window and Document can be considered as a common ancestor, try finding the closest to target. Referencing Window or Document is commonly used when listening for key events.
  - Once an ancestor is found, register it to the event. The ancestor will not only listen for registered events for itself -- it will listen for events triggered on any of its descendant elements as well. No need to register each element to one event and the amount of descendants that's covered is virtually limitless.
  - To determine and isolate the element that was actually clicked, changed, hovered over, etc -- use the Event property **[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)**.

The programming pattern described is the main part of **[Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)**.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main');

main.onclick = ddAccordion;

function ddAccordion(e) {
  const clicked = e.target;
  const triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');

  if (clicked.matches('.trigger')) {
    if (clicked.matches('.show')) {
      for (let t of triggers) {
        t.classList.remove('show');
      }
    } else {
      for (let t of triggers) {
        t.classList.remove('show');
      }
      clicked.classList.add('show');
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.trigger {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.trigger:hover,
.trigger:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
  outline: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.75s ease 0s;
}

.show+.content {
  max-height: 500px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: max-height 1.15s ease 0s;
}

.content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section class="dropdown">
      <button class="trigger">Dropdown 1</button>
      <address class="content">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </address>
    </section>
    <section class="dropdown">
      <button class="trigger">Dropdown 2</button>
      <address class="content">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </address>
    </section>
    <section class="dropdown">
      <button class="trigger">Dropdown 3</button>
      <address class="content">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </address>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```